# Combine received message parts on SMPP gateway

Tags: c#, inetlab.smpp

I use Inetlab.SMPP 2.8.1 (by licence reason) to implement an SMPP gateway. SMS message with long text must be split into small parts. Therefore I follow [the article](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/articles/faq/messagecomposer.html) and use a [`MessageComposer`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.Common.MessageComposer.html) instance to combine concatenated messages:

```cs
private void OnClientSubmitSm(object sender, SmppServerClient client, SubmitSm pdu)
{
    _composer.AddMessage(pdu);
    if (_composer.IsLastSegment(pdu))
    {
        string fullMessage = _composer.GetFullMessage(pdu);
        // do something
    }
}
```

where `_composer` is a `MessageComposer`.

But the code produces the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ThrowKeyNullException()
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
> at Inetlab.SMPP.Common.DefaultComposerItemStore.TryGet(String key, ComposerItem& item)
> at Inetlab.SMPP.Common.MessageComposer.IsLastSegment[TSmppMessage](TSmppMessage message)

Note, the similar code works well for `evDeliverSm` event. But it doesn't want to handle incoming `submit_sm` PDUs.

What I do wrong? And what do I must to do to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved using [`evFullMessageReceived`](https://docs.inetlab.com/smpp/v2.8/api/Inetlab.SMPP.Common.MessageComposer.evFullMessageReceived.html) event instead of checking message segments. So the following event handlers process incoming `SUBMIT_SM` PDU as expected:

```cs
// the method handles evClientSubmitSm event of SmppServer instance
private void OnClientSubmitSm(object sender, SmppServerClient client, SubmitSm pdu)
{
    try
    {
        _composer.AddMessage(pdu);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        pdu.Response.Header.Status = CommandStatus.ESME_RSUBMITFAIL;
        // log error
    }
}

// the method handles evFullMessageReceived event of MessageComposer instance
private void OnFullMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventHandlerArgs arguments)
{
    SubmitSm pdu = null;
    SmppClientBase client = null;

    try
    {
        pdu = arguments.GetFirst<SubmitSm>();
        client = pdu.Client;
        string fullMessage = arguments.Text;
        // save message
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        pdu.Response.Header.Status = CommandStatus.ESME_RSUBMITFAIL;
        // log error
    }
}

// the method handles evFullMessageTimeout event of MessageComposer instance
private void OnFullMessageTimeout(object sender, MessageEventHandlerArgs arguments)
{
    SubmitSm pdu = arguments.GetFirst<SubmitSm>();
    // log warning
}
```

Comment: But it is still interesting, why does `IsLastSegment` method fail?